# why I don't see generated IDs for server side controls?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-3.5

I'm little confused here now. Let me explain:

I've seen people talking about adding a button or some other control to the page in asp.net (3.5) and when the control renders it changes the Id of that control, eg. Button1 becomes Button1_somethingsomething which prevents them from using jQuery and what they end up using is something such as `<%controlId.ClientId %>`

So I did a little test

```
1. I added a button on the page:
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Button" />
<div>

2. Then I added a JavaScript and jQuery:
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#Button1").click(function() {
                        alert("Hello world!");
                    });

                    });
                </script>

3. The generated html is this:
<div>
  <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" />
<div>
```

Now, I don't see ASP.NET (asp.net 3.5) changing the ids. Why do I see different behavior?

Btw. This does work when I hit the button!

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET only changes the IDs when the control is inside of a [Naming Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx).  This could include certain user controls, ContentPlaceHolders from a master page, and repeating controls (Repeater, GridView, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You may not always need to use YourControl.ClientID, but it is good practice so that if and when your control DOES end up inside a container, you wont have to go back and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does not change the ID names by default, but does change them when they are used within a ContentPlaceHolder of a master page.  So the names end up being something like ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_Button1.  In your case, there is no master page and no change is made.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the INamingContainer Interface that certain controls (such as the asp:content control, used with master pages) implement.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx):

> Any control that implements this
>   interface creates a new namespace in
>   which all child control ID attributes
>   are guaranteed to be unique within an
>   entire application. The marker
>   provided by this interface allows
>   unique naming of the dynamically
>   generated server control instances
>   within the Web server controls that
>   support data binding. These controls
>   include the Repeater, DataGrid,
>   DataList, CheckBoxList,
>   ChangePassword, LoginView, Menu,
>   SiteMapNodeItem, and RadioButtonList
>   controls.

Your sample code does not use any of these controls. You do not use a Master Page with a ContentPlaceHolder. Your IDs are not altered because of this.